# How to select Slicer Items with an array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a sheet with a number of pivot tables in Excel, which are controlled by one slicer to set a specific filter. I'm able to abstract the Slicer Items with a VBA function found on the internet:

```
Public Function GetSelectedSlicerItems(SlicerName As String) As String
Dim oSc As SlicerCache
Dim oSi As SlicerItem
Dim lCt As Long
On Error Resume Next
Application.Volatile
Set oSc = ThisWorkbook.SlicerCaches(SlicerName)
If Not oSc Is Nothing Then
    For Each oSi In oSc.SlicerItems
        If oSi.Selected Then
            GetSelectedSlicerItems = GetSelectedSlicerItems & oSi.Name & ", "
            lCt = lCt + 1
        End If
    Next
    If Len(GetSelectedSlicerItems) > 0 Then
        If lCt = oSc.SlicerItems.Count Then
            GetSelectedSlicerItems = "All Items"
        Else
            GetSelectedSlicerItems = Left(GetSelectedSlicerItems, Len(GetSelectedSlicerItems) - 2)
        End If
    Else
        GetSelectedSlicerItems = "No items selected"
    End If
Else
    GetSelectedSlicerItems = "No slicer with name '" & SlicerName & "' was found"
End If
End Function
```

Now, what I want to do, is to select the same Items in a different Slicer on another worksheet. So I've found another piece of code here on StackOverflow from @jeffreyweir, that works fine, as long as the array is hardcoded:

```
Sub Set_VfMSlicer()

Dim slr As Slicer
Dim sc As SlicerCache
Dim si As SlicerItem
Dim i As Long
Dim vItem As Variant
Dim vSelection As Variant

Set sc = ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Afdeling")
'Set sc = slr.SlicerCache

vSelection = Array("DevOPs", "Functional Support", "Technical Support")

For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = True 'Stops PivotTable from refreshing after each PivotItem is changed
Next pt

With sc

    'At least one item must remain visible in the Slicer at all times, so make the first
    'item visible, and at the end of the routine, check if it actually  *should* be visible
    .SlicerItems(1).Selected = True

    'Hide any other items that aren't already hidden.
    'Note that it is far quicker to check the status than to change it.
    ' So only hide each item if it isn't already hidden
    For i = 2 To .SlicerItems.Count
        If .SlicerItems(i).Selected Then .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
    Next i

    'Make the PivotItems of interest visible
    On Error Resume Next 'In case one of the items isn't found
    For Each vItem In vSelection
        .SlicerItems(vItem).Selected = True
    Next vItem
    
    
    On Error GoTo 0

    'Hide the first PivotItem, unless it is one of the countries of interest
    On Error Resume Next
    If InStr(UCase(Join(vSelection, "|")), UCase(.SlicerItems(1).Name)) = 0 Then .SlicerItems(1).Selected = False
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        .ClearAllFilters
        MsgBox Title:="No Items Found", Prompt:="None of the desired items was found in the Slicer, so I have cleared the filter"
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End With


For Each pt In sc.PivotTables
    pt.ManualUpdate = False
Next pt

End Sub
```

I've tried to replace the `vSelection = Array("DevOPs", "Functional Support", "Technical Support")`

with: `str = GetSelectedSlicerItems("Slicer_Afdeling1") vSelection = Split(str, ",")`

which works, as long as only one item is selected in the source slicer. I want to be able to select multiple items as well. How can I fix this? The weird thing is that if a insert a msbBox in the loop to make the right items visible, it gives exactly the right items, which are also available in the slicer.

ps: the pivot tables are on different worksheets as well, but have the same range as source.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `GetSelectedSlicerItems("Slicer_Afdeling1")` actually returns the expected string?

Comment: That is really weird for me as noob: If I write the output of the arrays (hardcoded vs the array filled with the split string) to a cell range, I get exactly the same. However: If I compare the arrays with  a piece of code, it tells me that item 1 is a mismatch (which would explain why the first slicer Item is selected. I declare both arrays as Variant. What am I missing?

Comment: Should give the same results.  Are you able to share a workbook which replicates the problem?  Quite a bit of setup for me to troubleshoot otherwise...

Comment: Hmmm, feel stupid: While creating the demo sheet for you,  I just found out that I can select pivot tables on multiple sheets, but something strange was wrong with the source so they didn't show up in my initial workbook. I removed the slicers, changed the source (or actually reconfirmed them) and now I can select the department of all pivots on all sheets. Thanks!

Comment: I will still share the demo workbook, since I think it is interesting to find out why both  return a different result.